# Block a folder while allowing some url pattern inside it

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

*First am a newbie  with htaccess* .

**Down to Question**.

I have a structured folder like   public_html/account

Using htaccess, How can i block access to *domain.com/account*   while allowing access to url like  *domain.com/account/login*

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOgl0.png)

Is that even possible ?    I will love some help here .

Comment: what `domain.com/account` would be used for ?

Comment: Sorry i do n't understand your question ,  Are you asking what i will use the domain for or you want the domain name ?

Comment: Why do you want to restrict domain.com/account? Is it to be used by other users?

Comment: I just dont want users to view it since i already hav index.html in public_html .   The framework in /account folder is written on laravel ( which uses routes) and as a newbie i have only basic understanding of php .   Replacing the index.php in /account folder will be disaster  for me

Comment: So the /account folder contain a Laravel app ? But on a Laravel app, the web server usually points to a /public folder contained in the Laravel root app folder. In the end, I'm wandering if it'd not be easier to restrict your laravel route !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

**Option1**

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/account/login$"  allow  

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allow

Satisfy any
```

Not sure exactly what you have to put in `SetEnvIf Request_URI`, but it should be the request URI (this should be close).

Put this in `account/.htaccess`.

Basically it uses the Environmental variables to set a flag 'allow' if it matches a specific URI, then when you do the `allow` you can look for that environmental variable, which will only be set if the URI matched what you put in.

> The **mod_setenvif** module allows you to set internal environment variables according to whether different aspects of the request match regular expressions you specify. These environment variables can be used by other parts of the server to make decisions about actions to be taken, as well as becoming available to CGI scripts and SSI pages

You can also add more urls like this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/account/login$"  allow  
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/account/logout$"  allow
```

The problem with using Deny is it won't look very good.  There may be a way to fix that, but I am not sure how right off the top.  I think you can set an error page, maybe.

**Option2**

You may just want to redirect it somewhere else. Something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^accounts/?$ /accounts/login [L,R=301]
```

Sorry if I got a `/` or two wrong I always forget where to put them. I also have not used a complex rewrite for a long time, I used to do them more before I figured out how to route on the URI an not the query string.  Maybe 3-4 years ago ... lol

The Regex for this, URI starts with accounts and ends (or ends with a slash optionally), so it shouldn't match `/accounts/{anything}`. And you could also just redirect it to index.php or wherever you want too.

- `^` matches start URI
- `accounts` matches 'accounts' literally
- `/?` matches `/` literally `?` optional
- `$` matches end of URI (this is very important)

**UPDATE**

I looked it up :) and was like dooh.

If you set an error page (document) for `403` (access denied) error it will send to that when blocked and triggers the `403` code:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/account/login$"  allow  

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=allow

Satisfy any

ErrorDocument 403 /error/error.html
```

So I guess it depends if you want to issue the `403` access denied or `301` permanent redirect. I would base that on rather or not this part of the site shows up in search results. If it shows up on google for example do the `301` because then it will be (eventually) removed from the search results. I say that but they might also remove `401` pages to.  So it may just be personal preference.

One advantage of Deny is you could also password protect it (in the htaccess), that way you can access it with a login, but it wouldn't be publicly accessible. You could also do it with an IP address if you have a static one. Recently I did that for a an old site that used `CakePHP`, it was an easy $100 bucks (we'll there were a few other things I did for him, but I digress).

Cheers!

Hope it helps.